# How to move mails automatically from mailbox to personal folder in Outlook 2010?

Tags: windows, email, microsoft-outlook

I use Outlook 2010, and I have a personal folder (pst). Mails stay in mailbox, I expect them to come to Personal Folder's Inbox. How can I move mails automatically from mailbox to personal folder's inbox in Outlook 2010?

Comment: Sounds like you've opened an old Outlook version (pst from previous version) file with a newer version of Outlook. Is that correct? Are you trying to maintain the previous file's structure separately or can it be imported to the new version so all the messages and folders are together?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either use Outlook Archiving or you could add rules which route certain or all incoming mails to your personal folders.

The Archiving feature is time-oriented. All mails elder than a defined number of days/months get moved out of the inbox to some archive folder. This can be done a structure-preserving way, i.a. the folder/sub-folder struture of your online folder is reflected to the archive.

The rules can be added using Outlook's rule assistant. A "rule" selects incoming mails according to their subject, sender, addressee and other fields. The action part of the rule can copy, move or delete mails. It is also possible to spawn scripts or external programs.